# Запятые стоят правильно?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Не ложусь,Не спится и проспать,не хочу

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Это вообще одно предложение? Если да, то, конечно, в нем полный синтаксический кошмар. Кроме слов, которые требуют заглавной буквы (имен и т.п.), в предложении только одна большая буква - первая. После запятой должен быть пробел. В конце предложения - точка. В середине модальной фразы запятая не ставится. Причина и следствие разделяются двоеточием.

Comment: Пожалуйста, будьте внимательны и точны, когда составляете текст ответа.  1) Вообще - вводное слово или нет? 2) Модальная фраза - это что? 3) В БСП двоеточие ставится, когда "причина" на втором месте, а может и вообще  заменяться запятой, если автор не подчеркивает причинно-следственные отношения.

Comment: @Ксения, 2) как слависты называют фразу с модальным глаголом? "Не хочу проспать", "могу копать", "разрешили сделать" и т.п.. Я бы сказала, что тут не очень понятно, что же подчеркивает автор, кроме пауз, обозначенных запятыми. :)

Comment: Слависты? Сейчас посмотрим, кто это. СЛАВИСТ Специалист по славяноведению.  Не могу сказать, как это делают слависты, но фраза - это термин с разными значениями. В нашем же случае "не хочу проспать" -  односоставное предложение, в котором главным членом является составное глагольное сказуемое. В качестве связки в нем используется глагол с модальным значением. Согласитесь, что модальная связка и модальная фраза - это понятия разного уровня. А авторы бывают разные, иногда русский язык для них не родной. В этих случаях можно отредактировать вопрос или предложить вариант правки в ответе.

Comment: @Ксения, простите, но вы не звучите вежливо, мягко говоря. Свой, отличный от моего, ответ вы дали отдельно. Не думаю, что нуждаюсь в дальнейшей переписке в таком ключе. Автор вопроса задаст уточняющие вопросы в случае необходимости самостоятельно.

Comment: Я просто хотела сказать, что к ответам на этом форуме  предъявляются определенные ТРЕБОВАНИЯ со стороны системы, которая предоставила нам этот ресурс. Ответы должны быть грамотно оформленными,  точными по содержанию. Книжный стиль самого ответа предпочтительнее разговорного, но в комментариях разговорный стиль допускается. Извините, если что-то показалось Вам невежливым, хотя я теряюсь в догадках, что именно. Ну не слово же "пожалуйста" в начале комментария.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант правки:

**Не ложусь... Не спится, и проспать не хочу.**

1) После первого предложения нужно сделать паузу (точка, многоточие). Объединять все три предложения в одно сложное не имеет смысла.

2) *Не спится, и проспать не хочу*. Это ССП (сложносочиненное предложение), запятая перед союзом И ставится.

Оба предложения в составе ССП односоставные (безличное и определенно-личное).